# How do I parse this json to return the committee names

Tags: php, json

http://openstates.org/api/v1/legislators/NCL000018/

The committee names for the legislator are in the roles element. I've tried several different ways to do it but cannot retrieve all the committee names.

I want the committee: and the committee_id

The first part of my code looks like this

```
<?php

$leg_id='NCL000018';

$request_url = "http://openstates.org/api/v1/legislators/$leg_id/";
$ch = curl_init($request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
$legislator = json_decode($result);
print_r($legislator);

# Here is where I am stuck.

};

?>
```

I know I need a foreach loop but just cannot get the syntax right.

Comment: what is the key name for committe and commitee_id in the array?

Comment: Note that you also need this curl option: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Comment: Thanks for the quick replied. Problem solved. All of the answers were useful in helping me understand alternate ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot:

```
$legislator = json_decode($result);
foreach ($legislator->roles as $role) {
   if (isset($role->committee_id)) {
       echo $role->committee_id;
   }
   if (isset($role->committee)) {
       echo $role->committee;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may easily parse your JSON in array by passing true as second param in json_decode function.Array will be easy in iteration. You may try below code.

```
$leg_id = 'NCL000018';

$request_url = "http://openstates.org/api/v1/legislators/$leg_id/";
$ch = curl_init($request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
$legislator = json_decode($result, true);

if (is_array($legislator) && is_array($legislator['old_roles'])) {
    foreach ($legislator['old_roles'] as $years => $year_commity_arr) {
        foreach ($year_commity_arr as $commity_arr) {

            if (isset($commity_arr['committee'])) {
                echo $commity_arr['committee'] . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the advantage of this over using the object as returned by json?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$leg_id = 'NCL000018';
$request_url = "http://openstates.org/api/v1/legislators/$leg_id/";
$ch = curl_init($request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
$legislator = json_decode($result);
//print_r($legislator->old_roles);

foreach ($legislator->old_roles as $items) {
    foreach ($items as $committee) {
        if (isset($committee->committee_id)) {
            echo $committee->committee_id . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$leg_id='NCL000018';
$request_url = "http://openstates.org/api/v1/legislators/$leg_id/";
$ch = curl_init($request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
$legislator = json_decode($result);

echo '------------------------------------------';
foreach($legislator->roles as $k=>$committee){
    echo '<br/>';
    foreach($committee as $key=>$data){
        echo ($key=='committee_id') ? 'Id: '.$data.' - ':(($key=='committee')?'Name: '.$data:'');
    }
}
```

response:

```
------------------------------------------

Id: NCC000188 - Name: Workforce and Economic Development
Id: NCC000099 - Name: Appropriations on Education / Higher Education
Id: NCC000012 - Name: Health Care
Id: NCC000100 - Name: Education / Higher Education
Id: NCC000019 - Name: State and Local Government
Id: NCC000098 - Name: Appropriations / Base Budget
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
$legislator = json_decode($result);

$roles = $legislator->roles;
    foreach($roles as $role)
    {
        if(isset($role->committee_id))
            echo 'Committee Id: '. $role->committee_id;

        if(isset($role->committee))
            echo 'Commitee Role:' .$role->committee;
        echo '<br>';

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($array['roles'] as $roles){
    if(array_key_exists('committee_id', $roles)){
        echo 'Commitee ID: ' . $roles['committee_id'] . '<br>';
    }

    if(array_key_exists('committee', $roles)){
        echo 'Commitee: ' . $roles['committee'] . '<br>';
    }

}
```

See, if that helps.